# Unable to install Libreoffice and cjpeg Pimcore 5

Tags: php, linux, libreoffice, pimcore

I am installing Pimcore 5 and dependencies on Amazon EC2 Linux AMI(HVM)(t2.micro) with nginx1.2. There are these 2 packages which even if installed but not shown installed in Pimcore System requirement. 
I install Libreoffice as:

```
wget http://ftp.ussg.indiana.edu/tdf/libreoffice/stable/5.4.1/rpm/x86_64/LibreOffice_5.4.1_Linux_x86-64_rpm.tar.gz
yum remove openoffice* libreoffice*
tar -xvf LibreOffice_5.4.1_Linux_x86-64_rpm.tar.gz
cd LibreOffice_5.4.1.2_Linux_x86-64_rpm/RPMS
rm -rf libobasis5.4-gnome-integration-5.4.1.2-2.x86_64.rpm
yum install *rpm
```

Now output of whereis libreoffice5.4 come as

```
libreoffice5: /usr/bin/libreoffice5.4
```

But when check Pimcore then it showing not installed, In similar way I install cjpeg as given in https://www.pimcore.org/docs/5.0.0/Installation_and_Upgrade/System_Setup_and_Hosting/Additional_Tools_Installation.html and when do whereis cjpeg then it gives output

```
cjpeg: /usr/bin/cjpeg /usr/local/bin/cjpeg /opt/libmozjpeg/bin/cjpeg /usr/share/man/man1/cjpeg.1.gz
```

But still Pimcore showing it not installed.
What and where I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `app\config\parameters.yml` and add the paths to the cjpeg and soffice executables there. If that file doesn't exists make a copy of `parameters.example.yml`.